# Segmented Controllers or CollectionView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

ViewController has three buttons: "Friends" "Calendar" "Info". Each button is going to represent different information in the bottom half of this viewController.

My question is what to choose to represent this information - Segmented Controller or UICollectionView? [See attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyllH.png)

Comment: if your subviews (Friends, Calendar, Info) are simple views then a CollectionView may work for you but for more complex layouts and functionality, I would recommend a Segmented Controller with embedded views.

Comment: rmp thanks for your answer. Friends is going to have tableView inside, Calendar - also tableView, and only Info is going to have simple view inside.

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Comment: If it is helpful for you tell me.Otherwise I will delete my answer.

Comment: @SergeyNevzorov In that case, I would recommend using a Segmented Controller.

Comment: user3182143 yes, your answer is helpful, thank you. With collectionView I can set these three buttons as a collectionViewCells. When you tap one of these button it takes you to another collectionView, and each cell of the new collectionView will represent the actual Friends, Calendar and Info cells.

Comment: rmp, is it possible to customize segmented controller like in the image?

Comment: Yes, there are several tutorials online that can guide you. Here is one: http://smnh.me/customizing-appearance-of-uisegmentedcontrol/

Comment: Nice. Thank you rmp!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to go with UICOllectionView for acheive this?. If you go with SegmentControl it will be fine.If you set UICollectionView how do you do it?. If it is SegmentControll you can easily choose what you want. Also you can set it above the tableView.